# Running a VBA macro from a Visual C++ Application

Tags: vba, excel, visual-c++

My goal is to use my application (written in visual c++ 2010) to open some files in excel and run a macro written in VBA

Here is the code I have right now

```
try 
{
    System::Object^ oMissing = System::Reflection::Missing::Value;
    Excel::Application^ pExcel = gcnew Excel::Application();
    pExcel->Visible = true;


    Excel::Workbooks^ pBooks = pExcel->Workbooks;

    Excel::_Workbook^ pBook = pBooks->Open(_XLSFile, ... ); 
    Excel::_Workbook^ pBook2 = pBooks->Open(_XMLFile, ... );
    Excel::_Workbook^ pBook3 = pBooks->Open(_MacroFile, ... );

    pExcel->Run(macroName,  ... );

    // ....

}
catch(Exception^ e)
{
    System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(e->Message);
}
```

I've omitted the 20ish "System::Reflection::Missing::Value" parameters required for Open() and Run().

The Run command throws an exception, gets caught, and the message box shows the error:

```
Cannot run the macro '<macroName>'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled
```

My problem is that this message appears for one macro file but not another, even though they are very similar and both do indeed have the macro defined in them.

I think it has to do with macros being enabled, which excel makes the user do manually. My confusion is why it works with one file and not the other.

Any suggestions on how to fix this are greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The solution to my particular problem (though I'm not sure why it worked) was to put my macro file into 'design mode' in the VBA IDE

Comment: Are both macros Public?

Comment: I believe so. And I just tried it again with 'Public' before my Sub definition but I had the same problem

Comment: I don't know C++ but have you seen [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306686)?